# How to install Sextante in QGIS 1.8 without Plugin Installer?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, installation, sextante, download

How can I install sextante (and where can I download it) if the Plugin Installer doesn't works?

As I work for a corporation, I have some problems conecting to the official repository, and I cannot solve them ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download the most recent version of the SEXTANTE plugin [here](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/sextante/).

To install any plugins offline, you simply need to extract the downloaded archive to a folder and copy the extracted folder to the `~/.qgis/python/plugins`/ folder. The `.qgis` folder can be found inside the private document ("my documents") folder of your user on windows

Then start QGIS, open the plugin configuration dialog and activate the SEXTANTE plugin.