# Copy custom developed plugin from one computer to another

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I have developed a plugin on a PC running QGIS version 2.18. Now I would like to installed it on another computer running QGIS version 2.14 essen.

I have tried to copy by zipping the plugin and then extracted it to the ~/.qgis/python/plugins folder as instructed in the tutorial

[How to install Sextante in QGIS 1.8 without Plugin Installer?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/65289/how-to-install-sextante-in-qgis-1-8-without-plugin-installer)

But this technique did not work. Is there any specific method to archive the plugin folder on the source machine, or a way specify the path to the plugin on the destination machine?

Comment: To be clear, did you insert it here: `C:/Users/user_name/.qgis2/python/plugins/`? Also, make sure there's no extra folder (i.e. it should be `C:/Users/user_name/.qgis2/python/plugins/Custom_Plugin` and **not** `C:/Users/user_name/.qgis2/python/plugins/Custom_Plugin/Custom_Plugin/`). Another thing is to check if the minimum version of your plugin (which can be found in `metadata.txt`) is not lower than `2.14`.

Comment: have extracted it to C:/Users/user_name/.qgis2/python/plugins/MyPlugin. Folder MyPlugin contains the files in the plugin

Comment: Can you clarify on "this technique doesn't work"? Does it not load or does it not show up in the plugin manager?

Comment: Plugin does not showup in the manage

Comment: @Ashutosh - Did you restart QGIS 2.14 after you copied over the plugin?

Comment: After trying almost everything I have reinstalled QGIS. Next, I copied the plugin on this machine and everything seems OK. I can now access the plugin that I have copied. Considering all of the above, I have concluded that the previous copy of QGIS was somehow corrupted and therefore I was facing the plugin installation issue. If anyone faces a similar issue try reinstalling QGIS.